# my method is printing wrong numbers from the array?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arrs = {5, 7, 4, 9, 8, 10};
    int maxLength = LIS(arrs, 0);
    System.out.println("Length of LIS: " + maxLength);

}

public static int LIS(int[] arr, int n) {

    if (n == arr.length) {
        return 1;
    }

    int counter = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = n; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] >= max && arr[i] < max + 5) {
            max = arr[i];

            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            
            
            counter++;
            System.out.println(counter);
            
        }
    }
    
       return counter;
    
}
```

}

It should be printing:

```
5
1
7
2
9
3
10
4
Length of LIS: 4
```

but it prints:

```
4
1
8
2
10
3
Length of LIS: 3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: 5 is not less than 0 + 5, so I wonder what made you expect the result you claim this code should print.

Comment: Your question did include example input (`arrs`), example expected output, and example actual output, and code, as it should. What is lacking is an explanation of what `LIS`  is intended to do.  Please edit the question to include that. When I see a question like this, I want to be able to see *why* the example expected output is supposed to be the correct output for the example input. I want to be able to look at the code and compare what it is intended to do with what it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

why are you initially setting max to 0?
that's not how you find a max value in an array.
what if all numbers in the array are less than zero?

also 5 is not less than 0 + 5!

```
int max = arr[0];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for submitting your first ever answer to Stack Overflow! When answering questions, consider using the comments to answer further questions when trying to help someone out. Also, it looks like the code you have suggested may not be solving the issue of the user, but instead pointing out a potential change in just one section of the code. This too is a good thing to put in a comment, but as it does not solve the question, it's best not to post answer's that don't answer the question :)

Comment: I realize you don't have enough reputation points to be able to comment on a question or answer (other than your own). It can be frustrating, I know. But, answers really should be answers here. Using the answer box to make a comment, including asking for clarification, is regarded as counterproductive here.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

It looks like the `if` statement within the `for` loop is not quite doing what you want it to. The condition `arr[i] >= max && arr[i] < max + 5` allows for numbers less than the previous number as long as they are within 5 of the maximum seen so far, which isn't the correct logic for implementing LIS.

You can correct this with the following code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arrs = {5, 7, 4, 9, 8, 10};
    int maxLength = LIS(arrs, 0);
    System.out.println("Length of LIS: " + maxLength);

}

public static int LIS(int[] arr, int n) {

    int counter = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = n; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            counter++;
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
    
    return counter;
}
```

Using this code, the LIS should be correctly identified as the counter can only ever increase, not decrease within 5 like your code does.